# Is it possible to process a 4 dimensional netCDF file in R?

Tags: arrays, r, matrix, multidimensional-array

I am aware of the `ncdf` package of R.

I am trying to plot wind speed and wind direction(4D) of WRFout netCDF file.
Variable as a function of `(i,j,k,l)`.

New variables need to be created as the calculation shown in the code.
Looping through 4 for loops is taking too long. I understand advanced looping techniques such as plyr or tapply or mapply exist. But examples for these are only for 2D array/matrix.

Please suggest optimization package for 4D array.

```
library(ncdf)
ncin <- open.ncdf("wrfout.nc")
imax <- 425  #No of grids in Longitude
jmax <- 200  #No of grids in Latitude
kmax <- 40   #Vertical layers
lmax <- 11   #Time
paiv <- atan(1.0)/45.0
#However, UUin and VVin are in staggerd grid from input file
#dim(UUin) is (426,200,40,11)
#dim(VVin) is (425,201,40,11) 
UUin <- get.var.ncdf(ncin,"U")
VVin <- get.var.ncdf(ncin,"V")
#Initialize arrays in normal grid 
UU <- array(0.0, c(imax,jmax,kmax,lmax))
VV <- array(0.0, c(imax,jmax,kmax,lmax))
Wspd <- array(0.0,c(imax,jmax,kmax,lmax))
Wdir <- array(0.0,c(imax,jmax,kmax,lmax))
for (l in 1:lmax) {
for (k in 1:kmax) {
for (j in 1:jmax) {
for (i in 1:imax) {
#Change U and V staggerd grid to regular grid
UU[i,j,k,l] <- 0.5*(UUin[i,j,k,l]+ UUin[i+1,j,k,l])
VV[i,j,k,l] <- 0.5*(VVin[i,j,k,l]+ VVin[i,j+1,k,l])       
#Now calculate wind speed and direction in regular grid
Wspd[i,j,k,l] <- sqrt(UU[i,j,k,l]*UU[i,j,k,l] + VV[i,j,k,l]* VV[i,j,k,l])
if (UU[i,j,k,l] == 0.0) 
{  # startif   
if(VV[i,j,k,l] < 0.0) 
Wdir[i,j,k,l] = 0.0     
else  
Wdir[i,j,k,l] = 180.0
}
else   
Wdir[i,j,k,l] = atan2(VV[i,j,k,l], UU[i,j,k,l]) / paiv
if(UU[i,j,k,l] < 0.0) {
Wdir[i,j,k,l] = 90.0 - Wdir[i,j,k,l]  
}  
else  
Wdir[i,j,k,l] = 270.0 - Wdir[i,j,k,l]  
if (Wdir[i,j,k,l] < 0.0) 
{      
Wdir[i,j,k,l] = Wdir[i,j,k,l] + 360.0
} 
if (Wdir[i,j,k,l] > 360.0) 
{
Wdir[i,j,k,l] = Wdir[i,j,k,l] - 360.0      
}    
}    #end of i 
}    #end of j 
}    #end of k 
}    #end of l
```

Comment: add code what u've tried

Comment: What i have is 4D netCDF file with lat, lon, elevation and time.
I have posted my code below. I have variables like U, V, P and PB in my file.